# Seaborn countplot per feature value

Tags: seaborn

I have a dataset as follows:

[image]

The 'island' features has three possible values: Torgensen, Biscoe Island and Dream. I'm printing as Seaborn countplot as follows:

```
fig = sns.countplot(data=dataset, x='Island', hue='Species');
```

[image]

I'm getting the above.

I would like to have three seperate plots though per island. I tried the following but that does not work:

```
fig = sns.countplot(data=dataset, x='Island['Torgersen', hue='Species');
fig = sns.countplot(data=dataset, x='Island['Biscoe Island', hue='Species');
fig = sns.countplot(data=dataset, x='Island['Dream', hue='Species');
```

But that does not seem to work. Any idea how I can achieve three plots (one plot per island) instead of 1 plot (having all three islands)?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), and then map `sns.countplot` to each of the subplots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dataset = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=dataset, col='island')

species = dataset['species'].unique()
g.map(sns.countplot, 'species', order=species, palette='turbo')
for ax in g.axes.flat:
     ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.FacetGrid with sns.countplot]

PS: You can also plot this via one call to `sns.displot` (this will use the same color for all the bars).

```py
g = sns.displot(data=dataset, kind='hist', stat='count', col='island', x='species', shrink=0.8)
```